# Attach existing record to eloquent hasMany / belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model `SalesArea` which hasMany `Regions`. `Regions` belongTo one `SalesArea`.

```php
class SalesArea extends Model
{
    public function regions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Region');
    }
}

class Region extends Model
{
    public function sales_area() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SalesArea');
    }
}
```

Due to some changes in organization, the parent (SalesArea) is being created after the Regions have been created. I am trying to associate the Regions with their associated Sales areas when the Sales Area record is created.

I created a migration to add sales_area_id to the `regions` table, and they are currently all null.

I have a select box that has the various IDs of Regions and I would like to associate the regions with a Sales Area at once with an array of ids. None of the association methods are working.

```php
$area = SalesArea::create($request->all());

$area->regions()->attach([1,2,3]); // BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

$area->regions()->add([1,2,3]); // BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::add()'

$area->regions()->sync([1,2,3]); // BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()'

$area->regions()->associate([1,2,3]); // BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()'
```

I am stumped on how this is supposed to work. Regions already exist, I just need to add their relationships to their associated sales area.

Comment: Does `1,2,3` are region ids? To my knowledge `attach()`, `sync()`, `associate()` are related to the `belongs to many` relation. You can't use them here.

Comment: `->attach()`, `->detach()` and `->sync()` are only usable on many-to-many relationships, i.e. relationships with a pivot. You've got a one-to-many (many-to-one) defined here, so these won't work.

Comment: So what *can* I use in a one-to-Many?

Comment: BelongsTo can use associate(), HasMany (or HasOne) uses save().  You could just update the foreign key value too, you don't always have to use the methods outlined.

Comment: @Devon ok say I have $regions = Region::where('id', [array of IDs]); then I do $area->regions()->saveMany($regions);

It doesn't appear to actually associate the Regions or save their records.

Comment: You loop over the `Region`s and update their `sales_area_id` to that of the `SalesArea` you want them to be associated with.

Comment: Why not just do `Region::whereIn('id', [$ids])->update(['sales_area_id' => $area->id]);`

Comment: @TimLewis was hoping to avoid loops and just get it all to work in one query

Comment: `Region::where('id', [array of IDs]);` won't be a collection of `Region`s, but a `QueryBuilder`, so using that in `->saveMany()` won't do much. Gotta use `->get()` first. And yeah, I'm sure there's a way to avoid looping, but that's an example.

Comment: Oh yeah, `whereIn()` for multiple (array of) column values, `where()` for single.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
       'name' => 'required|unique:sales_areas',
       'regions' => 'required|array',
       'regions.*' => 'int',
    ]);

    $salesArea = SalesArea::create($request->all());

    // Because we have a hasMany not a many to many, we have to do it this way
    Region::whereIn('id', $request->regions)->update(['sales_area_id' => $salesArea->id]);

    flash('Created Sales Area ' . $salesArea->name);
    return redirect()->route('areas.index', $salesArea->id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you have the column, `sales_area_id` in your `regions` table

```
$salesArea = SalesArea::create($request->all());

$regions = Region::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();

$salesArea->regions()->saveMany($regions);
```

I am not sure, why you are creating the regions this way. If there is a `hasMany()`relation between SalesArea & Region then all regions should be created like :

```
$salesArea->regions()->create([ ... ]);
```

And if your relations are like this

```
class SalesArea extends Model
{
    public function regions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Region::class)->withPivot(['id'])->withTimestamps();
    }
}

class Region extends Model
{
    public function sales_area() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SalesArea::class)->withPivot(['id'])->withTimestamps(
    }
}
```

then you can do something like this.

```
$salesArea = SalesArea::create($request->all());

$regions = Region::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();

$salesArea->regions()->sync($regions->pluck('id')->toArray());
```

Comment: The nature of real-world application development. Regions already exist, and for all intents and purposes cannot be changed. Sales Area is a new thing that they want to group them all by. So we can't create new ones as the areas are created, we must group the existing ones with new Sales Areas.

Comment: With your edit, that would require an additional table, would it not?

Regions can only belong to _one_ SalesArea, so the hasMany / belongsTo relationship is more accurate to how the data needs to be accessed.

Comment: @Oranges13 Just updated the English. I wanted to know if you were sure about the relations that you were using. If you know what you are doing, then you can ignore the thing I said about changing relations. :)